# how to move pin front to view in map?

Tags: android, android-mapview

move the pin to front when we click on pin in map please suggest any solution to do this

Answer (score 0):

Best answer: Write your own `Overlay` to have this capability.

Possible answer: Play around with the order of the `OverlayItems` in your `ItemizedOverlay`. That may control which is "on top", but I am not completely certain. And, since that behavior is not documented, it might change in the future.